# Component rendered in `describe` is not visible in `it` using react-testing-library

Tags: react-testing-library

When I render a component in `it` block everything works as expected.

```
  it("when user inputs more characters it displays suggestions", async () => {
    const { getByLabelText, findByText } = render(<Component />);

    debug();
  });
```

It's not a good practice though. I prefer using `it` only for assertions. When I do:

```
  describe("when user inputs more characters ", async () => {
    const { getByLabelText, findByText } = render(<Component />);

    it("displays suggestions", () => {
      debug();
    });
  });
```

debug shows only `<body />` and all queries fails in `it` block.

What am I doing wrong or why this is not supported?

Answer (score 0):

They both work, the problem is that you must put your `render` inside the `it` block. That's because you can't reuse a rendered component

Comment: This is ok for this simple example. In most cases though you need to setup a test case and perform some actions. It is a good practice to separate those sections (given, when, then). In jest, most people use `beforeEach`. What if you would like to do something like this: https://gist.githubusercontent.com/mazikwyry/c5db71fcd9afca9c80fbe40b459f0082/raw/992ee91f25ce952c557280804c82020dc740ba85/gistfile1.txt

Comment: You can move the _before_ logic in a `setup` function and call it at the beginning of your `it` blocks